# Covariance function of the cosines of two random variables

Tags: correlation, random-variable, covariance

I have the following question:
Let $\Phi_1(x)$ and $\Phi_2(y)$ be two random variables with uniform distributions $\mathrm{U}[0,2\pi]$ (actually $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are two random fields so that $x$ and $y$ are two points in $\mathbb{R}^3$). The spatial correlation (covariance) function of these random variables writes: $R_{\Phi_1(x),\Phi_2(y)}(x,y) = \mathbb{E}[\Phi_1(x)\Phi_2(y)]-\mathbb{E}[\Phi_1(x)]\mathbb{E}[\Phi_2(y)] = \mathbb{E}[\Phi_1(x)\Phi_2(y)]-\pi^2$. I wonder if it is possible to relate the correlation function of the random variables $\cos \Phi_1(x)$ and $\cos \Phi_2(y)$, i.e. $R_{\cos \Phi_1(x),\cos \Phi_2(y)}(x,y) = \mathbb{E}[\cos\Phi_1(x)\cos\Phi_2(y)]$ (averages of the cosines of random variables vanish), to the covariance function $R_{\Phi_1(x),\Phi_2(y)}$.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosine of a uniform random variable $U[0,2\pi]$ is distributed as an [ArcSin random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution).

You can easily work this out since the density of a uniform random variable here looks like $f_U(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$. If your random $\Phi$'s aren't independent not much more can be said.

Comment: Isn't that the question?  Just what *can* be said when the variables are not independent?  If the answer truly is "not much more," then could you provide examples or an argument to show why it's impossible to place any bounds on the correlation of the cosines from the given information?

Comment: @Alex R: thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot.